# Does itertools.product evaluate its arguments lazily?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

The following never prints anything in Python 3.6

```
from itertools import product, count

for f in product(count(), [1,2]): 
    print(f)
```

Instead, it just sits there and burns CPU. The issue seems to be that `product` never returns an iterator if it's over an infinite space because it evaluates the full `product` first. This is surprising given that the `product` is supposed to be a generator.

I would have expected this to start counting up (to infinity), something like the behavior of this generator (taken [directly from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)):

```
for tup in ((x,y) for x in count() for y in [1,2]):
    print(tup)
```

But whereas my generator starts counting immediately, the one using `product` never counts at all.

Other tools in `itertools` do what I'd expect. For example, the following:

```
for f in takewhile(lambda x: True, count()): 
    print(f)
```

will print a stream of numbers because `takewhile` is lazy.

Comment: DeepSpace's answer is misleading: product is _not_ lazy, so far as I can tell, given that it takes (I assume) infinite time to return, whereas the equivalent example in the documentation does as I expect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) generates its results lazily, but this is not true for the arguments. They are evaluated eagerly. Each iterable argument is first converted to a tuple:

The evaluation of the arguments (not the production of results) is very similar to the Python implementation shown in the docs:

```
...
pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
```

Whereas, in the [CPython implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2072), `pools` is a tuple of tuples:

```c
for (i=0; i < nargs ; ++i) {
     PyObject *item = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, i);
     PyObject *pool = PySequence_Tuple(item);   /* here */
     if (pool == NULL)
         goto error;
     PyTuple_SET_ITEM(pools, i, pool);
     indices[i] = 0;
 }
```

This is so since `product` sometimes needs to go over an iterable more than once, which is not possible if the arguments were left as iterators that can only be consumed once.

You practically cannot build a tuple from an `itertools.count` object. Consider *slicing* to a reasonable length with `itertools.islice` before passing to `product`.

Comment: This answer saved me from filing a bug report with python, well done.

Answer (score 1):

I found that

```
for tup in ((x,y) for x in count() for y in [1,2]):
    print(tup)
```

does what I expect. This is odd given that it [is listed as equivalent in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). This seems like a bug in `itertools.product`, but it seems unlikely given how standard it is.

Comment: It is listed as "roughly" equivalent and the statement is that it returns the same value. I think this certainly leaves room for the possibility that one is lazy and the other is not.

Answer (score -1):

> The issue seems to be that product never returns an iterator

No, `product` is already "lazy".

The issue is that`count()` counts to infinity. 
From `count`'s [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

Equivalent to:

```
def count(start=0, step=1):
    # count(10) --> 10 11 12 13 14 ...
    # count(2.5, 0.5) -> 2.5 3.0 3.5 ...
    n = start
    while True:
        yield n
        n += step
```

You code is basically the same as doing:

```
def count():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i += 1

count()
```

Comment: I'm confused, shouldn't the loop start counting (to infinity)? The issue is that it doesn't return anything from `count`

Comment: I added an example where I get what I'd expect from a lazy evaluated function.

Comment: @Shep `count()` is evaluated *first*, the rest of the code is never reached, so to speak

Comment: Count returns an iterator, evaluating it takes very little time.

Comment: @Shep See my updated asnwer. Your code tries to evaluated a an **infinite** generator (`count()`). Nothing is breaking it and the rest of your code is never even executed as Chris said.

Comment: @Shep `evaluating it takes very little time` Not if "it" is infinite...

Comment: OK, so the problem is that it eagerly evaluates `count()` before returning. I want a version of `product` that evaluates the inputs lazily

Comment: @Shep You're still not being clear on your desired output, do you mean something like this? `for c in count(): print(list(product([c],[1,2])))`

Comment: I believe so, yes. I also added a generator that does exactly what I need. The question is if there's a builtin function that does what `product` is doing, but that evaluates the `count()` lazily.

Comment: @Shep No, it isn't evaluated eagerly. It is evaluated item by item but there are infinitly many items.

Comment: ok, so taking it straight from the docs: "`product(A, B)` returns the same as `((x,y) for x in A for y in B)`". I don't find this to be true when `A` is `count()`

Comment: try it in python 3.6, the behavior isn't the same. But anyway, I think I've answered my question.

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct. You quote the docs which _say_ product is lazy, but my tests show otherwise.