# Design MapReduce function to find intersection sets between list of sets

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, set

Suppose I have multiple lists

```
L1 = [{2,7},{2,7,8},{2,3,6,7},{1,2,4,5,7}]      
L2 = [{3,6},{1,3,4,6,7},{2,3,5,6,8}]      
L3 = [{2,5,7,8},{1,2,3,5,7,8}, {2,4,5,6,7,8}]
```

The intersection sets between each element of L1, L2, and L3 are:

```
{2,7}.intersection({3,6}).intersection({2,5,7,8})= empty  
{2,7}.intersection({3,6}).intersection({1,2,3,5,7,8})= empty  
{2,7}.intersection({3,6}).intersection({2,4,5,6,7,8})= empty  
{2,7}.intersection({1,3,4,6,7}).intersection({2,5,7,8})= {7}  
{2,7}.intersection({1,3,4,6,7}).intersection({1,2,3,5,7,8})= {7}  
{2,7}.intersection({1,3,4,6,7}).intersection({2,4,5,6,7,8})= {7}
...............................
```

If we keep doing like this, we end up with the following set:

```
{{empty},{2},{3},{6},{7},{2,3},{2,5},{2,6},{2,8},{3,7},{4,7},{6,7},{1,7}}
```

Suppose I have many lists L1, L2, L3,...Ln. How can I design Map and Reduce function to calculate intersections between sets of these input lists.

Please help. I just need only the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can't possibly fit in a single Map/Reduce job. I don't really think this use case is well suited for the M/R paradigm in general, as it doesn't seem to parallelize well and involves a huge amount of data to be shuffled.

For the sake of simplicity, I'll just translate the input and operator to simpler versions, keeping their properties intact. Instead of lists of sets and intersection, lets assume you have lists of numbers and sums (for our purpose, this should be equivalent).

So you want to compute all possible sums of numbers chosen from different lists:

Input:

```
L1: [1, 2, 3]
L2: [4, 5]
L3: [6, 7]
```

Results:

```
[
  1+4+6, 1+4+7, 1+5+6, 1+5+7,
  2+4+6, 2+4+7, 2+5+6, 2+5+7,
  3+4+6, 3+4+7, 3+5+6, 3+5+7
]
 = [11, 12, 12, 13, 12, 13, 13, 14, 13, 14, 14, 15]
```

And after removing duplicates, you'll end up with:

```
[11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

*Checkpoint: please confirm that I got your requirements right.*

To end up computing the sums in the reducer, every element in each list needs to be outputted from the mapper under a number of keys that is equal to the lengths of all the other lists multiplied; and the keys need to allow joining all combinations of elements from different lists in the reducer.

Since the lists are not necessarily of the same size, you can only ensure the above if you know the exact length of every other list in the dataset when you evaluate each list record. (This prior knowledge means another M/R job to produce the array of lengths.) Then, you can compute the key by concatenating every possible index combination of elements.

In our example, the value '1' (which is index 0 in L1), will be emitted under the following keys: `"000"` (i.e. `1+4+6`), `"001"`, `"010"`, `"011"` (exploring all possible paths from '1' through the rest of the lists). For value '7' (index 1 in L3), we'll have: `"001"`, `"011"`, `"101"`, `"111"`, `"201"`, `"211"`.

Once you do this, you'll end up in the reducer with the numbers to sum up under the same key (which is exactly what you wanted, except that you still have duplicate sums at this stage):

```
"000" -> [1, 4, 6]
"001" -> [1, 4, 7]
...
"211" -> [3, 5, 7]
```

But this is quite a lot of data to shuffle! Of course, you can use the reducer as a combiner also, but still: with N lists of size M, you would emit the elements in each list M^N times. And I assume N is in the millions (at least), otherwise you wouldn't consider map/reduce.
Moreover, every key that you output from map will be a string of length N (the number of lists in the dataset). So you can easily end up with MB-sized keys (even if you switch to a more compact binary format).

And for this to work, you'll need a prerequisite job that computes the array of list sizes and, finally, the deduplication may need yet another job (unless you're writing to some storage which does that for you).

To conclude, there must be a better way...
If your data set fits in memory on a single node, do give that a try. The intersections that you're computing will narrow down naturally and (if you're lucky) most of them will end up as the empty set quick enough.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your design is for 1 Mapreduce job, right? Is there any way solve the problem using multiple jobs?

Comment: I have tried this way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206395/find-intersection-sets-between-list-of-sets.  I split the input list into n parts, calculate intersection for each part (each part is 1 mapper). Then, I intersect the output of those mappers in my reducer. However, to get the right result, the number of reducer has always to be 1, which decrease the parallelism capacity. Am I right?

Comment: Computing the partial intersections for each split is already ensured by the combiner that I mentioned. But how do you build the map output keys so that you won't intersect (say) `[1,4]` with `[2,4]` in the reducer? Or was this not a requirement?

Comment: Suppose there are L1, L2, L3,..Ln. Mapper1 returns L12=intersect(L1,L2), Mapper2 returns L38=intersect(L3,L4,..L8), Mapper3 returns L915=intersect(L9,..L15), Mapper4 returns L16n=intersect(L16..Ln). Do you think that intersect(L1,..Ln) = intersect(L12, L38, L915, L16n) ? I think it is right. But not so sure. If it is right, I can use several mappers and 1 reducer right?

Comment: If I got this right, L12=intersect(L1,L2) is actually a collection of intersections: each element in L1 intersected with each element in L2. Besides, how do you get to have in the reducer L12, L38, L915 and L16n under the same key?

Comment: I concat all elements of L12 to be a string, each element divided by a "|".  E.g. output of Mapper 1 will be <key, "s11|s12|s13|s14">. Similarly, output of Mapper2 will be <key, "s21|s22|s23|...">, output of Mapper3 will be <key, "s31|s32|....". All these mappers will have the same key. In the Reducer, I take values of these Mappers, convert them to lists, e.g, L1=[set(s11), set(s12),set(s13),set(s14)], L2=[set(s21),set(s22),set(s23)], L3=[set(s31),set(s32)]. Then, I calculate intersect(L1, L2, L3) as the final result.

Comment: Because i am not so sure if my approach is right, please confirm it for me. Thank you.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't make much sense. Looks like your mapper does nothing but transport each record (list of sets) to the reducer, in some serialized format. The reducer then iterates over the whole dataset found under a single key (say, the "dataset" key). So you're back one node reading the full raw dataset, but you just delayed it with a useless map phase. And the whole thing still needs to fit in memory in the reducer.

Comment: In fact, each s11, s12, s13, s14 is an intersection between my L1 and L2, i.e., the Mapper1 already calculated intersections between L1 and L2. So do Mapper2 and Mapper3. The output of each Mapper is also a list, i.e., I have 3 output lists. Then again I calculate intersection btw these output lists in my reducer. This method, has a limitation, however. Because I have only 1 Reducer. More mappers lead to more inputs to reducer (only 1), which sadly makes the whole program slower.

Comment: Back to your method. I try to implement it. Luckily, to my problem, N and M is not so huge. So, number of keys = N*M is not a problem. However, I find that the order of keys is very important. As you said, the number 1 is emitted only in keys "000" (i.e. 1+4+6), "001", "010", "011" but not other keys. Similarly, the number 7 is emitted only in keys "001", "011", "101", "111", "201", "211". How can I emit the right key for each element of each list? Given that I have lengths of all lists

Comment: Dear, could you tell me how to emit keys for an element of each list? I am still stuck at here. I am desperate now. :(

Comment: @cdt, please don't call me "dear". :)
The number of keys is not N*M, it's M^N (M to the power of N); and you'll have to emit the whole key space while processing each single record (e.g. L1).
The algorithm I described was meant to discourage you from trying map/reduce. If you want to pursue with it, you'll need to just iterate through all the lists (except the current one) and assemble all index "paths": after: L1, you'll have: "0", "1", "2", "3"; after L2: "00", "01", "02", "10, "11", "12", "20", "21", "22", "30", "31", "32". See where this is heading?

Comment: Can you describe the original problem instead, rather than the list of sets abstraction? You may get better help for that.

Comment: Thanks. I want to try your method even its M^N. The problem to me now is to find index "paths" for each list. Could you explain more how to "assemble all index "paths": after: L1, you'll have: "0", "1", "2", "3"; after L2: "00", "01", "02", "10, "11", "12", "20", "21", "22", "30", "31", "32"." ?

Comment: My original problem is more complicated than this. To solve my problem, I have used several mapreduce jobs, and this problem is one of the jobs. So I have to use mapreduce too. Btw, to solve my problem sequentially ( not parallel), I think the complexity is O(M^N) right?

Comment: I'm now hoping someone will come up with a better idea, as I'd feel guilty if you proceeded with this one. :) Anyway: to compute all possible keys for (say) number 7 above: that's index 1 in L3, so you'll emit the value 7 for all the keys that have "1" as the 3rd character (and all possible combinations of prefixes and suffixes for all the other lists in the dataset). The prefixes will be "00", "01", "10", "11", "20", "21". You append "1" as the 3rd char to all these and continue with the rest of the lists to append suffixes.