# Why does itertools.product run through all elements at initialization?

Tags: iteration, generator, python-3.7

I assumed that `itertools.product` generates elements one at the time. I am now noticing that it is not true.
Simple proof of concept:

```
Class A:
  def __init__(self, n):
    self.source = iter(range(n))

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    val = next(self.source)
    print("I am at:", val)
    return val
```

Now If I do:

```
from itertools import product
l = product(A(3), A(3))
print("Here")
next(l)
```

I expect to have as output:

```
>'Here'
>'I am at 0'
>'I am at 0'
```

But I have

```
>'I am at 0'
>'I am at 1'
>'I am at 2'
>'I am at 0'
>'I am at 1'
>'I am at 2'
>'Here'
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question we need to look at the implementation of [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

[here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2104) you find the real C implementation, but to answer this question, it is enough to refer to python (see the EXTRA paragraph at the bottom).

focus on this line of code:

```
pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
```

in this way all the elements of the two iterators (taken in input) are transformed into a list of tuples (only the first time you call `next()`), and at this time they are actually created.

Returning to your code, when you call `next(l)` for the first time, all elements of the iterators are created. In your example the list will be created the `polls` list with the following elements:

```
# pools: [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
```

which is why you got those outputs.

---

As for the `print("Here")`, to understand why it is printed first you need to understand how the generators work:

`itertool.product()` returns a generator object. The generator does not execute the function code until it is stimulated by the first `next()`. Subsequently, each call `next()` allows you to calculate the next element, executing only once the loop containing the keyword `yield`.

[Here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/) you will find excellent resources to better understand how python generators work.

---

#### Why did 'itertools' choose to keep the list of tuples in memory?

Because the Cartesian product must evaluate the same element several times, and iterators cannot instead be consumed only once.

---

#### EXTRA

in C the list of tuple [pools](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2148) it is created equivalent to python, as you can see from this code, are evaluated eagerly. Each iterable argument is first converted to a tuple:

```
pools = PyTuple_New(npools);
if (pools == NULL)
    goto error;

for (i=0; i < nargs ; ++i) {
    PyObject *item = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(args, i);
    PyObject *pool = PySequence_Tuple(item);
    if (pool == NULL)
        goto error;
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(pools, i, pool);
    indices[i] = 0;
}
for ( ; i < npools; ++i) {
    PyObject *pool = PyTuple_GET_ITEM(pools, i - nargs);
    Py_INCREF(pool);
    PyTuple_SET_ITEM(pools, i, pool);
    indices[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not how it's really implemented, how can you be sure of your answer then?

Comment: There is the implementation in the `itertools.product` documentation. If you look in my answer there is also a link to the documentation where you can see the code. However you can find it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: "This function is roughly equivalent to the following code, except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory" - what am I missing here?

Comment: Of course, itertools is implemented in C (I added the link in the answer). The code is C equivalent is equivalent to the python that they give in the documentation, as far as this question is concerned. The tuple list is created "exactly" in the same way.

Comment: Sure, I'm happy I was also able to contribute to you answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that while for both instances of `class A` the `__next__` method gets called exhaustively (until `StopIteration` is encountered), the `itertools.product` iterator is still lazy evaluated with the subsequent calls to `next`. Notice that:

> > 'I am at 0'
>
> > 'I am at 1'
>
> > 'I am at 2'
>
> > 'I am at 0'
>
> > 'I am at 1'
>
> > 'I am at 2'
>
> > 'Here'

is just a result of calling exhaustively `next` first for the first passed instance, and then for the second. This is more readily seen when calling `product(A(2), A(3))`, which results in:

> > 'I am at 0'
>
> > 'I am at 1'
>
> > 'I am at 0'
>
> > 'I am at 1'
>
> > 'I am at 2'

The same behavior is observed for `combinations` and `permutations`. In fact searching for so informed question with "Does itertools.product evaluate its arguments lazily?" brought me to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586863/does-itertools-product-evaluate-its-arguments-lazily) which also answers your question. The arguments are not evaluated lazily:

> since `product` sometimes needs to go over an iterable more than once, which is not possible if the arguments were left as iterators that can only be consumed once.

Comment: That makes lots of sense. I think that @Massifox answer is more extensive so if by the end of the bounty I don't get other answers I'll accept his. But you've been really helpful!