# Generator expressions vs generator functions and surprisingly eager evaluation

Tags: python, generator, yield

For reasons which are not relevant I am combining some data structures in a certain way, whilst also replacing the Python 2.7's default `dict` with `OrderedDict`. The data structures use tuples as keys in dictionaries. Please ignore those details (the replacement of the `dict` type is not useful below, but it is in the real code).

```
import __builtin__
import collections
import contextlib
import itertools


def combine(config_a, config_b):
    return (dict(first, **second) for first, second in itertools.product(config_a, config_b))


@contextlib.contextmanager
def dict_as_ordereddict():
    dict_orig = __builtin__.dict
    try:
        __builtin__.dict = collections.OrderedDict
        yield
    finally:
        __builtin__.dict = dict_orig
```

This works as expected initially (`dict` can take non-string keyword arguments as a special case):

```
print 'one level nesting'
with dict_as_ordereddict():
    result = combine(
        [{(0, 1): 'a', (2, 3): 'b'}],
        [{(4, 5): 'c', (6, 7): 'd'}]
    )
print list(result)
print
```

Output:

```
one level nesting
[{(0, 1): 'a', (4, 5): 'c', (2, 3): 'b', (6, 7): 'd'}]
```

However, when nesting calls to the `combine` generator expression, it can be seen that the `dict` reference is treated as `OrderedDict`, lacking the special behaviour of `dict` to use tuples as keyword arguments:

```
print 'two level nesting'
with dict_as_ordereddict():
    result = combine(combine(
        [{(0, 1): 'a', (2, 3): 'b'}],
        [{(4, 5): 'c', (6, 7): 'd'}]
    ),
        [{(8, 9): 'e', (10, 11): 'f'}]
    )
print list(result)
print
```

Output:

```
two level nesting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 36, in <module>
    [{(8, 9): 'e', (10, 11): 'f'}]
  File "test.py", line 8, in combine
    return (dict(first, **second) for first, second in itertools.product(config_a, config_b))
  File "test.py", line 8, in <genexpr>
    return (dict(first, **second) for first, second in itertools.product(config_a, config_b))
TypeError: __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Furthermore, implementing via `yield` instead of a generator expression fixes the problem:

```
def combine_yield(config_a, config_b):
    for first, second in itertools.product(config_a, config_b):
        yield dict(first, **second)


print 'two level nesting, yield'
with dict_as_ordereddict():
    result = combine_yield(combine_yield(
        [{(0, 1): 'a', (2, 3): 'b'}],
        [{(4, 5): 'c', (6, 7): 'd'}]
    ),
        [{(8, 9): 'e', (10, 11): 'f'}]
    )
print list(result)
print
```

Output:

```
two level nesting, yield
[{(0, 1): 'a', (8, 9): 'e', (2, 3): 'b', (4, 5): 'c', (6, 7): 'd', (10, 11): 'f'}]
```

Questions:

1. Why does some item (only the first?) from the generator expression get evaluated before required in the second example, or what is it required for?
2. Why is it not evaluated in the first example? I actually expected this behaviour in both.
3. Why does the `yield`-based version work?

Comment: You pasted your 'one level nesting' code a second time, rather than the 'two level nesting' code.  One thing that is probably causing at least part of your problem: changing `__builtin__.dict` *only* affects explicit references to `dict`, NOT `{...}` dictionary literals.

Comment: I've fixed the copy-paste error. I don't think dictionary literals are causing the problem - what makes you say that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before going into the details note the following: [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) evaluates the iterator arguments in order to compute the product. This can be seen from the equivalent Python implementation in the docs (the first line is relevant):

```
def product(*args, **kwds):
    pools = map(tuple, args) * kwds.get('repeat', 1)
    ...
```

You can also try this with a custom class and a short test script:

```
import itertools


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        print('next item requested')
        if self.x < 5:
            self.x += 1
            return self.x
        raise StopIteration()


t = Test()
itertools.product(t, t)
```

Creating the `itertools.product` object will show in the output that all the iterators items are immediately requested.

This means, as soon as you call `itertools.product` the iterator arguments are evaluated. This is important because in the first case the arguments are just two lists and so there's no problem. Then you evaluate the final `result` via `list(result` *after* the context manager `dict_as_ordereddict` has returned and so all calls to `dict` will be resolved as the normal builtin `dict`.

Now for the second example the inner call to `combine` works still fine, now returning a generator expression which is then used as one of the arguments to the second `combine`'s call to `itertools.product`. As we've seen above these arguments are immediately evaluated and so the generator object is asked to generate its values. In order to do so, it needs to resolve `dict`. However now we're still inside the context manager `dict_as_ordereddict` and for that reason `dict` will be resolved as `OrderedDict` which doesn't accept non-string keys for keyword arguments.

It is important to notice here that the first version which uses `return` needs to create the generator object in order to return it. That involves creating the `itertools.product` object. That means this version is as lazy as `itertools.product`.

Now to the question why the `yield` version works. By using `yield`, invoking the function will return a generator. Now this is a truly lazy version in the sense that execution of the function body doesn't start until items are requested. This means neither the inner nor the outer call to `convert` will start executing the function body and thus invoking `itertools.product` until the items are requested via `list(result)`. You can check that by putting an additional print statement inside that function and right behind the context manager:

```
def combine(config_a, config_b):
    print 'start'
    # return (dict(first, **second) for first, second in itertools.product(config_a, config_b))
    for first, second in itertools.product(config_a, config_b):
        yield dict(first, **second)

with dict_as_ordereddict():
    result = combine(combine(
        [{(0, 1): 'a', (2, 3): 'b'}],
        [{(4, 5): 'c', (6, 7): 'd'}]
    ),
        [{(8, 9): 'e', (10, 11): 'f'}]
    )
print 'end of context manager'
print list(result)
print
```

With the `yield` version we'll notice that it prints the following:

```
end of context manager
start
start
```

I.e. the generators are started only when the results are requested via `list(result)`. This is different from the `return` version (uncomment in the above code). Now you'll see

```
start
start
```

and before the end of the context manager is reached the error is already raised.

On a side note, in order for your code to work, the replacement of `dict` needs to be ineffective (and it is for the first version), so I don't see why you would use that context manager at all. Secondly, `dict` literals are not ordered in Python 2, and neither are keyword arguments so that also defeats the purpose of using `OrderedDict`. Also note that in Python 3 that non-string keyword arguments behavior of `dict` has been removed and the clean way to update dictionaries of any keys is to use `dict.update`.

Comment: My understanding was that `itertools.product`, being part of `itertools`, was lazy (and also from the phrase "except that the actual implementation does not build up intermediate results in memory" in the documentation. However, as you say (and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586863/does-itertools-product-evaluate-its-arguments-lazily), the arguments are indeed consumed eagerly. I had also expected the pre-`yield` code of a generator function to execute immediately, yielding only at the `yield` statement.

Comment: Your final paragraph: as I said in the question, the details of the dictionary ordering are not relevant here; they are used in the wider context. `dict.update` is not a one-for-one substitute for the keyword argument constructor, since it returns `None`. I guess that means Python 3 has no elegant dictionary update expression.

Comment: @SamBrightman With `dict.update` you'll have to use `dict.copy` beforehand, yes, so it is not a one-liner. But it will work on both major versions of Python so upgrading to PY3 does not require any changes. Python 3 does have a one-liner for merging dicts, namely `{**first, **second}` but this doesn't work under Python 2. In addition, there's [PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/) about adding `+` and `+=` for dicts but it's still a draft.

Comment: Regarding usage of `OrderedDict`, I see, so your goal was to circumvent the replacement with `OrderedDict` by making the generation of `result` fully lazy and only request the items outside of the context manager?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. PEP 584 got a bit more [traction](https://lwn.net/Articles/803189/) recently.